# What does やがんだ mean?

Tags: grammar, usage

Right now, I'm reading the Japanese translation of Catcher in the Rye.

This sentence has been puzzling me:

奴さん、ジャガーをもってやがんだよ。

I know that the author is saying that his brother owns a Jaguar, but I'm not sure what 「やがんだ」 means exactly.

So my question is: How is やがんだ used and when is it used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a colloquial contraction of 〜て[やがる](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%84%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B)＋んだ, from 〜て＋いやがる＋のだ.  Holden thinks that his brother is a big phony because he has a Jaguar, and he's expressing his negative attitude toward that with 〜てやがる.